# difficulty in making a divided plane turning into a whole plane

Tags: rendering

i am trying to remove the vertices of the selected portion to make it as a whole .
But i can not figure that out . Can anyone help?[image: i am trying to remove the vertices of the selected portion to select it as a whole .]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "to make it as a whole"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all three faces that make up the ground plane and hit <kbd>F</kbd> to merge them.

The extra vertices can be selected individually and "dissolved" without breaking the face with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

You can in fact skip the first step; dissolving the vertices on the rim merges the faces as well.

Comment: thank you @DustinCompetent